# zynq 7000 while reading the data in Linux environment data is written only in alternative locations

Tags: embedded-linux, xilinx, zynq

I am working on zynq7030.
I have written data from an image sensor to DDR memory using AXI DMA, but while reading the data in Linux environment data is written only in alternative locations.
Example, if we read data from DDR the sensor's data is written only in 0x0, 0x8.  Data in 0x4 and 0xC are junk values instead of sensor data.

Custom AXI (full) master -> Interconnect -> Zynq_PS (HP0 slave port)

The custom AXI master produces data (simple counter, written to DRAM, starting at 0x10000000).
according to xsct console -> mrd 0x10000000 10

0x000165c9
0x000266ca
0x000367cb
0x000468cc
0x000569cd

BUT in linux while reading

Please check below the output when I read the DDR location from 0x10000000 using peek command.

root@swan1GB:~# peek 0x10000000; peek 0x10000004 ; peek 0x10000008 ; peek 0x1000000C ; peek 0x10000010

0x000165c9----->data

0x0cbfb405------->garbage data

0x000367cb------->data

0xe0c84100-------->garbage data

0x000569cd-------->data

As we can see the first location has a counter pattern(0x000165C9), the second location should have been written with 0x000266CA but it has some junk value.

Comment: Incomplete description of problem: no details of hardware, no code.  Vote to close.  *"alternative locations"* -- Seems like you really mean 'alternate bytes'.  DMA transfer width and/or increment versus the width of source data register could be out of whack.

Comment: i have updated now@sawdust